# html tidy and javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tidy, htmltidy

When HTML Tidy see this HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var left =  /</g
</script>
```

It generates

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var left =  /<\/g
</script>
```

which causes the run-time error: unterminated regular expression literal.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just avoid using </something in the script since it could confuse some browsers as closing tag. Use \x3c instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var left =  /\x3c/g
</script>
```

Comment: Or one could use: `/[<]/`